Becker-Barro Model (1988, QJE)
I'm struggling in getting the first-order necessary condition in the Barro-Becker model.
Consider the following setting:
Suppose that each person
has two periods of life: childhood and adulthood.
We have the following dynastic utility function
\begin{equation}
U_0 = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \alpha^{i} (N_i)^{1-\epsilon} \nu (c_i)
\end{equation}
where $n_i$ is the number of children, $\nu(c_i)$ is the utility function of the adult in generation $i$, $c_i$ is the consumption of an individual in generation $i$.
The term $N_i$ denotes the number of descendants in the i-th generation:
\begin{equation}
N_0=1, ~~ N_i= \prod_{j=0}^{i-1} n_j, ~ i=1,2,\dots
\end{equation}
The budget constraint of the adult in generation $i$ is
\begin{equation}
w_i + (1+r_i)k_i = c_i + n_i(\beta_i + k_{i+1})
\label{budget_c}
\end{equation}
where $w_i$ is the wage rate. Parents leave a bequest of non-depreciable capital, $k_{i+1}$, to each child at the beginning of the child's adulthood.
Capital $k_i$ pays a net rate $r_i$ at each period in time. An adult in generation $i$ spends his earnings and inheritance, $w_i + (1+r_i)k_i$, on own consumption, $c_i$,
on bequests to children, $n_i k_{i+1}$, and on costs of raising children to adulthood, $\beta_i n_i$.
Let $\sigma(c_i)$ denote the elasticity of $\nu(c_i)$ w.r.t. $c_i$, and this yields:
\begin{equation}
\sigma(c_i)= \frac{ \nu'(c_i) c_i}{\nu(c_i)} 
\end{equation}
I write infinite-horizon Lagrangian function w.r.t. $c_i$, $k_{i+1}$ and $N_i$ as
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L} = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \alpha^{i} (N_i)^{1-\epsilon} \nu (c_i) + \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \lambda_i\left[ w_i + (1+r_i)k_i - c_i - n_i(\beta_i + k_{i+1}) \right]
\end{equation}
First-order necessary conditions:
For $c_i$ :
\begin{equation}
    \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial c_i} = 0 \quad \text{i.e.} \quad \alpha^i (N_i)^{1-\epsilon} \nu'(c_i) = \lambda_i
    \label{foc1}
    \end{equation}
For $k_{i+1}$:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial k_{i+1}} = 0 \quad \text{i.e.} \quad \lambda_{i} n_{i} = \lambda_{i+1}(1+r_{i+1})
\end{equation}
Then, I recognize that $N_{i+1} = \prod_{j=0}^{i} n_j$, and thus $n_i = \frac{N_{i+1}}{N_{i}}$. and trivially, $N_i = \frac{N_{i+1}}{n_{i}}$. Using this result into the 2 FOCs above, I get
\begin{equation}
\frac{ \nu'(c_i) }{\nu'(c_{i+1})} =  \frac{\alpha (1+ r_{i+1})}{(n_i)^{\epsilon}}, ~~i=0,1,...
\end{equation}
What I am struggling to derive is the second set of FOCs, which I assume should result from differentiating the Lagrangian with respect to $N_i$. This yields the following condition:
\begin{equation}
\nu(c_i) [1-\epsilon - \sigma(c_i)] = \nu'(c_i)[\beta_{i-1} (1+r_i) - w_i]
\end{equation}
Any help?

Rewrite $n_i = N_{i+1}/N_i$ in the budget constraint before taking the first order condition with respect to $N_i$. Then you will see that the first order conditions with respect to $N_i$ has a dynamic component: $N_i$ enters two budget constraints, the one for period $i$ and the one for period $i+1$. Hope this helps.
